# Bash script to remove 'x' amount of characters the end of multiple filenames in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a list of file names in a directory (`/path/to/local`). I would like to remove a certain number of characters from all of those filenames.

**Example filenames:**

```
iso1111_plane001_00321.moc1
iso1111_plane002_00321.moc1
iso2222_plane001_00123.moc1
```

In every filename I wish to remove the last 5 characters before the file extension.

**For example:**

```
iso1111_plane001_.moc1
iso1111_plane002_.moc1
iso2222_plane001_.moc1
```

I believe this can be done using `sed`, but I cannot determine the exact coding. Something like...

```
for filename in /path/to/local/*.moc1; do
    mv $filname $(echo $filename | sed -e 's/.....^//');
done
```

...but that does not work.  Sorry if I butchered the `sed` options, I do not have much experience with it.

Comment: `^` is the beginning of a line, by definition there cannot be anything before it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 mv $filname $(echo $filename | sed -e 's/.....\.moc1$//');
```

or

```
 echo ${filename%%?????.moc1}.moc1
```

%% is a bash internal operator...

Comment: Thanks! The second option you presented worked perfectly in the bash script.

Comment: sed example is wrong (doesn't account for the extension) but +1 for the  bash solution

Comment: @glennjackman, I did, but none of the edits seem to refer to the extension. Even the first edit includes the `.moc1` extension. What am I missing? Just trying to spot my mistake.

Comment: Facepalm, by 'sed example' I thought you were referring to my answer. Now after seeing Zoltan's `sed` answer, I'm realizing that mine is WAY over complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` command will work for all the examples you gave.

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)_.*\.moc1/\1_.moc1/'
```

However, if you just want to specifically "remove 5 characters before the last extension in a filename" this command is what you want:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)[0-9a-zA-Z]\{5\}\.\([^.]*\)/\1.\2/'
```

You can implement this in your script like so:

```
for filename in /path/to/local/*.moc1; do

    mv $filename "$(echo $filename | sed -e 's/\(.*\)[0-9a-zA-Z]\{5\}\.\([^.]*\)/\1.\2/')";

done
```

**First Command Explanation**

The first `sed` command works by grabbing all characters until the first underscore: `\(.*\)_`

Then it discards all characters until it finds `.moc1`: `.*\.moc1`

Then it replaces the text that it found with everything it grabbed at first inside the parenthesis: `/\1`

And finally adds the `.moc1` extension back on the end and ends the regex: `.moc1/`

**Second Command Explanation**

The second `sed` command works by grabbing all characters at first: `\(.*\)`

And then it is forced to stop grabbing characters so it can discard five characters, or more specifically, five characters that lie in the ranges 0-9, a-z, and A-Z: `[0-9a-zA-Z]\{5\}`

Then comes the dot `'.'` character to mark the last extension : `\.`

And then it looks for all non-dot characters. This ensures that we are grabbing the **last** extension: `\([^.]*\)`

Finally, it replaces all that text with the first and second capture groups, separated by the `.` character, and ends the regex: `/\1.\2/`

Comment: Thanks for the code to strip based on the character - even though it wasn't the OPs question - it was mine

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(.*).{5}\./\1./' file
```