# Bash script to remove chars from all filenames in folder

Tags: bash

I have a folder with few images, all have the same name format:

```
some-random-name-min.jpg
another-random-name-min.jpg
and-another-random-name-min.jpg
```

I want to strip the last `-min` so following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751498/bash-script-to-remove-x-amount-of-characters-the-end-of-multiple-filenames-in)

I tried this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in /home/al/domus-images/portfolio/white snow/*.jpg; do
    mv $filname $(echo $filename | sed -e 's/....\.jpg$//');
done
```

but after running the script nothing happened..any idea what am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` command to list the files and then to remove `-min` from file name follow below script.

```
for filename in `find "/home/al/domus-images/portfolio/white snow/" -name "*.jpg"`;
do
    mv $filname $(echo $filename | sed 's/-min.jpg$/.jpg/');
done
```

This remove last "-min" from file name.

Comment: Why the _g_ at the end of the sed-directive?

Comment: @Bex Thanks for correcting, here `g` is not required.

Answer (score 2):

this could be an idea:

```
#!/bin/bash    
for filename in *\-min.jpg
do
    newFile=$(echo $filename |sed "s/\-min//g")
    printf "before\t:filename[$filename]\tnewFile[$newFile]\n"
    mv $filename $newFile
    printf "after\t:filename[$filename]\tnewFile[$newFile]\n"
done
```

output

```
[shell] ➤ ./myMove
before  :filename[and-another-random-name-min.jpg]      newFile[and-another-random-name.jpg]
after   :filename[and-another-random-name-min.jpg]      newFile[and-another-random-name.jpg]
before  :filename[another-random-name-min.jpg]  newFile[another-random-name.jpg]
after   :filename[another-random-name-min.jpg]  newFile[another-random-name.jpg]
before  :filename[some-random-name-min.jpg]     newFile[some-random-name.jpg]
after   :filename[some-random-name-min.jpg]     newFile[some-random-name.jpg]
```

this `*\-min.jpg` is just to be sure to get only the file you need

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in /home/al/domus-images/portfolio/white snow/*-min.jpg
do
    mv ${filename} ${filename//-min.jpg/.jpg}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't get it simpler than this.

```
rename 's/\-min.jpg$/.jpg/' *-min.jpg
```